# how to reinstall ubuntu as part of dual boot with windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 15.10, lenovo

As in this [previous](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728311/install-ubuntu-desktop-no-cddrive-no-internet) question, my Ubuntu has crashed unrepairably, so I must reinstall.  Currently I have a dual boot partition with Windows 10 (working fine) and Ubuntu 15.10 (dead).

My laptop is a Lenovo Yoga 3, which is too narrow to have a <del>USB</del> ethernet cable or a [CD drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60782/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-as-part-of-dual-boot). Also, I have a flash drive with Ubuntu formatted as an [ISO](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Imitating the steps of the original installation, used a [Windows 10 trick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) to boot from the hard-drive.  But when I click "try ubuntu" it puts the Ubuntu screen and freezes.

Any guidelines for re-installation?

Comment: According to my research the Yoga 3 has at least one (Micro-)USB connector. Both adapter cables from Micro-USB to regular USB and USB hubs are cheap and imho by far the easiest option to install Ubuntu from USB.